# how to apply consumer info to a mlt file as shotcut does

Tags: xml, mlt

I'm using both melt command line and shotcut to do video editing.

I'd like to check the xml by right click on the Jobs window, which sits on the right side of shotcut Application window, and click the "View XML" after the job has been done. Here is my xml.
[here is the xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUCi9.png)

As you can see above. There are some information about **consumer**. So I save this as a mlt file named stackoverflow_1.mlt.

And I can get the same video file output as shotcut does if I do the command:

```
.\melt.exe .\stackoverflow_1.mlt -progress
```

This is absolutely fantastic! Because the mlt file generated by melt.exe directly doesn't has these message, so I needed to call melt twice to do the same thing before.

So I will show you how to do the same thing with melt.exe. Here is the thing, I prefer to generate a mlt file before exporting video. so I would type these commands:

The first step:

```
.\melt.exe .\buck_20s.mp4 in=00:00:04.160 out=00:00:09.440 -consumer xml:buck.mlt
```

[here is my mlt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjTY4.png). The mlt file doesn't has the message about **consumer**.

The second step:

```
.\melt.exe .\buck.mlt -consumer avformat:buck_5s.mp4
```

And you may ask why not just do it like this?

```
.\melt.exe .\buck_20s.mp4 in=00:00:04.160 out=00:00:09.440 -consumer avformat:buck_5s.mp4
```

Okay,that's definitely right. But that will generate nothing except the final video file and I want to the xml file to store the video-editing information.

the mlt file doesn't has the consumer info, So I can't just type like this:

```
.\melt.exe xxx.mlt
```

So my question is how can I apply consumer info to mlt file use melt command line as shotcut does. I hope I have make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is how can I apply consumer info to mlt file use melt
>   command line as shotcut does.

You can't. This is currently not implemented/supported by the melt command line utility.

Shotcut adds the "consumer" element manually after creating the XML document:
https://github.com/mltframework/shotcut/blob/master/src/docks/encodedock.cpp#L749

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I checked the code and I'm going to insert the "consumer" element manually in my application as shotcut does. Beyond that, I also noticed that there is a playlist named "main bin" in the mlt file generated by shotcut, which contains all of resource files in the playlist whatever it is used or not. But the mlt file, generated by my command line, doesn't have these message. I try to delete the "main bin" and the appendant "producer" and run the mlt file with melt.exe directly, It still works. I'm curious about the purpose of these elements. Is it used to speed up video exporting?

Comment: “Main bin” maps to the playlist feature in Shotcut. It allows the user to keep track of files they have opened in the project - even if they are not used in the timeline.